# Exoplayer how to retry from beginning

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have a simple ExoPlayer, I load it as the following code:

```
List<MediaItem> mediaItems = new ArrayList<>(playlist.size());

for (String url : playlist) {
    mediaItems.add(MediaItem.fromUri(url));
}

player.setMediaItems(mediaItems);
player.prepare();
player.setRepeatMode(player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE);
```

It works fine, and I made it works offline.

My question is: sometimes there are some network problems, and the player stops. Is there some way to resume or start from the beginning (because it is already in the cache)?